Implementing real-time bitmap scaling with SSE2 intrinsics
I have this code that blits a bitmap onto the frame buffer with SSE2 intrinsics:
for (uint r = 0; r < height; r++)
{
    uint32* bufPixels = (frameBuffer->pixels + xPos) + frameBuffer->pitch * (r + yPos);
    uint32* bmpPixels = bitmap->pixels + bitmap->pitch * r;

    for (uint p = 0; p + NUM_SIMD_PIXELS /* 4 */ <= width; p += NUM_SIMD_PIXELS)
    {
        __m128i bmpVec = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)(bmpPixels + p));

        _mm_storeu_si128((__m128i*)(bufPixels + p), bmpVec);
    }
}

I want to implement scaling into this, but I can't grasp myself on any ideas without having to resort to scalar operations.
With SSE2 I am always working with 4 pixels at once and thus I can't just loop over width * xScale and do p / xScale on each of the pixels to get the actual pixel index in the bitmap's pixel buffer.
Not really looking for code examples, more just ideas.
EDIT: here is a scalar example of the scaling I wish to accomplish:
for (uint r = 0; r < height * yScale; ++r)
{
    uint bmpRowIndex = (uint)(r / yScale);

    uint32* bufPixels = (frameBuffer->pixels + xPos) + frameBuffer->pitch * (r + yPos);
    uint32* bmpPixels = bitmap->pixels + bitmap->pitch * bmpRowIndex;
    for (uint p = 0; p < width * xScale; ++p)
    {
        uint bmpPixelIndex = (uint)(p / xScale);
        bufPixels[p] = bmpPixels[bmpPixelIndex];
    }
}

It's basic nearest-neighbor sprite scaling, nothing fancy. I just want this but in SIMD.

So you are just doing sample based rescaling?  Are you scaling up or down?  (upscaling sample based is different than downscaling sample based in many ways)  Downscaling sampling you are doing rare source samples (so sse reading doesn't make much sense; maybe writing might somehow).  Upscaling you are reading every pixel and then writing it to a wide set of destination pixels (the memset operation could be faster with SSE?)  ... maybe masked store/loads?  I mean, I sort of doubt it.

@yakk I'm not sure what you mean by "sample based rescaling". I just want to scale sprites dynamically at arbitrary scale values like you would see in pixel art games (like this).

For many practical use cases, the best thing you can do is rendering a textured quad using a 3D GPU API, e.g. D3D11 if you target Windows.

@nasir Rescaling an image down by a factor of X with minimal informatiom loss can involve serious math.  Eben upscaling.  I am uncertain how to describe the problem to someone completely unaware of it.  But, as an example, take a 4x4 sized block of 1 pixel wide white and black vertical lines.  When rescaled to 2x2  should it be grey or solid white or solid black?

@yakk you seem to be misunderstanding my use case here. My intention with this code is writing a simple software renderer for a 2D game. I am aware of the losing pixels issue (doesn't that happen with every single image scaler?). The "quality" of scaling doesn't matter at all to me since it's only for a game.


For a 2D image, you will have to effectively implement 2 scaling algorithms - horizontal and vertical ones. Even if the fundamental math is the same for both. 2. You'll have to choose the algorithm for scaling as that will determine its complexity/performance and quality. Some examples are: nearest neighbour, bilinear, bicubic, and in the latter case - with which coefficients.



For each output sample, you will need to load samples from the input image that will contribute to that output sample and then add them with weights defined by the scaling algorithm. The weights and positions of the input samples can be precomputed and cached, if you need to scale multiple images with same scaling ratios. Note that for horizontal scaling you will normally load multiple consequent input samples in one load, and you can leverage that to reduce the number of loads. But you will also likely have to shuffle samples in the loaded vector before accumulating.



For data shuffling, you will probably need _mm_shuffle_epi8, for accumulation and weighting _mm_madd_epi16 and _mm_maddubs_epi16 are useful. For performance, you should stay in the INT domain in the hot loop, which means weighting must be done in fixed point. _mm_maddubs_epi16 expects one of the operands to be signed 8-bit integers, which means you will only have 7 bits of precision in this weighting step. You would normally use the signed argument for the 7-bit weighting coefficients. This should be enough for decent quality, but if it isn't, you'll have to use _mm_madd_epi16.


@Nasir Can you post a scalar example code of what you want to achieve (could be pseudo code, but make sure input and output formats are specified)? It seems you only want nearest-neighbor scaling (no bi-linear or bi-cubic interpolation)? Is your scaling factor more or less fixed (at least for long enough to allow some precalculations)? Can it really be arbitrary, or is it ok to limit it to a smaller set of possibilities (e.g., 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0, 1.25, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 4, 6, ...)?

@Nasir If quality doesn't matter, just output black.  It is a very low quality high speed solution!  Andrey is giving a pile of different ways to do scaling; I suspect you are thinking "nearest neighbour".  In general for scaling an image, you want to "imagine" the infinite resolution version (what does it look like?) and how that maps to a pixel color (is a pixel a point sample?  A square integral over a region?  A triangular integral over a region?  Something else?), with care taken it is reversible.  You'll also want to care about what to do with sample aliasing artifacts.

Or, you can just punt and not worry about that.  However, if you really don't care about quality, a solid black result is a low quality solution; so really, what you care about is quality, but not that much.  I can't answer how much you care about quality; I suspect you can't either, because you don't know how bad it gets in your actual game.  However, if you want speed, try pre-process MIP-MAPPING your images (store 1/2 resolution versions, recursively), then implement scaling up from a mip-map when you scale down.  You'll now only need to support fast upscaling.

@chtz it needs to be arbitrary. By input/output format do you just mean the image format? It's RGBA (4 bytes per pixel). And correct, I only want nearest-neighbor. Scale factor is not fixed. See my edit.

The good news is you're happy with nearest neighbor scaling, which is the simplest to implement.  The bad news is that SIMD works with values that are adjacent to each other, and with nearest neighbor that won't be true of your pixels anymore.

Especially for downscaling vpgather* instructions are worth looking at – of course you can write a generic solution with it, but for upscaling and minor downscaling it will probably not be very efficient.

Based on the comments, it seems you only interested in the nearest neighbor resampling, and only for RGBA8 pixel format. I think for your use case, SIMD is borderline useless. While it is possible to do something smart with _mm_shuffle_epi8 or if you have AVX with _mm_permutevar_ps, not sure you going to have much profit from these, if at all.
Assuming you compile for 64 bits, try the following version. The code is untested but I hope the idea is clear. I’ll be surprised to find it’s possible to speed up with SIMD by any meaningful margin, unless restricting the scaling multiplier into small rational numbers.
#include <stdint.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>

struct RgbaBitmap
{
    // Bitmap data in system memory
    uint32_t* pointer;
    // Distance between rows; expressed in uint32_t elements, not bytes
    size_t rowPitch;
    // Size of the bitmap
    int width, height;
};

// End value for that 32.32 fixed-point number, incremented by `step` on each iteration
inline uint64_t scaledEnd32( uint64_t step, int rt, int sprite )
{
    if( rt > 0 && sprite > 0 )
    {
        // End value for the input sprite
        uint64_t sprite64 = (uint32_t)sprite;
        uint64_t endSprite = sprite64 << 32;
        // End value for the output bitmap
        uint64_t rt64 = (uint32_t)rt;
        uint64_t endRt = rt64 * step;
        // Return the minimum of them
        return std::min( endSprite, endRt );
    }
    else
        return 0;
}

void scaleBitmap( const RgbaBitmap& target, const RgbaBitmap& sprite,
    int xPos, int yPos, float scaling )
{
    // Supporting negative xPos / yPos is possible but rather tricky, not doing in this example
    assert( xPos >= 0 );
    assert( yPos >= 0 );
    assert( scaling > 0.0 );

    // Compute inverse of the scaling multiplier.
    // The following codes need to scale opposite way, output pixels -> sprite pixels.
    // Also convert into 32.32 fixed point, rounding for optimal precision.
    constexpr double p32 = (double)( (int64_t)1 << 32 );
    const uint64_t step = (uint64_t)std::llround( p32 / scaling );

    const size_t destPitch = target.rowPitch;
    const size_t sourcePitch = sprite.rowPitch;
    uint32_t* rdiLine = target.pointer + yPos * destPitch + xPos;
    const uint64_t fxEnd = scaledEnd32( step, target.width - xPos, sprite.width );
    const uint64_t fyEnd = scaledEnd32( step, target.height - yPos, sprite.height );

    // The outer loop is by output rows
    for( uint64_t fy = 0; fy < fyEnd; fy += step, rdiLine += destPitch )
    {
        // Sprite Y coordinate for the current output row
        const size_t sourceY = ( fy >> 32 );
        assert( (int64_t)sourceY < sprite.height );
        // Source pointer to read from the sprite
        const uint32_t* const rsi = sprite.pointer + sourcePitch * sourceY;

        // The inner loop is within a single row, each iteration makes an output pixel
        uint32_t* rdi = rdiLine;
        for( uint64_t fx = 0; fx < fxEnd; fx += step, rdi++ )
        {
            const size_t sourceX = ( fx >> 32 );
            assert( (int64_t)sourceX < sprite.width );
            *rdi = rsi[ sourceX ];
        }
    }
}

If you compile for a 32 bit CPU where 64 bit integer arithmetic is expensive, refactor the code into 16.16 fixed point i.e. use (double)( 1 << 16 ) multiplier and shift numbers by 16 bits when sampling from the source sprite.

I think I may have come to the conclusion that I should just stick to my scalar code..

@Nasir Yeah, but the scalar code in your question uses division on the hot path, relatively slow even on modern CPUs. The scalar code in my answer doesn’t, it only uses multiplications and bit shifts, both are quite fast.
